# invoking a separate script in %pre section of rpm spec file

Tags: linux, rpm, specifications, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I am preparing an rpm package. 
My post install actions were complex. So I created a separate postinstall script file to do that which gets invoked from my spec file. It just works fine.

Now I am focusing on prescript. Can I have a separate script file which can be invoked from the %pre section of the spec? I know that the file won't be available in the desired location before installation(still will be in the package). I just want to keep my spec file as simple as possible.